Romance movie from before 2000 about a college-aged couple on a road trip
I am looking for a romance movie before 2000.
The language is English and the movie is probably set in USA.
This movie is about a "cool" young guy and a "not so cool" young girl - who was studying at a university - who are going on a road trip together and they get to know each other this way.
The girl was dating a nerd and that's why he liked this guy so much.
I also remember that they run out of money in their trip.

Do you have any other details? What the people looked like, where was the film set, what language was it in?

The Sure Thing? I never saw it. I am guessing based on a list of road trip movies. Or possibly Y Tu Mama Tambien, but that one was about a 3-way couple. Wild at Heart is also a possibility but those guys look older than college.

Yes it's the sure thing thank you so much.

@Hack-R Seems one of your guesses is correct. Can you please make it an answer?

@Hack-R Pretty sure he says "it's the sure thing".

@Catija  got it!

It was The Sure Thing.

I determined this via a combination of guessing and a "Top 25 Road Trip Movies" list I found online.
